# How to read variable number of lines from the terminal?

Tags: node.js

I need to ask how many inputs the user want to give (one input per line) and read them.

I am trying to keep it as simple as possible without using any libraries or even `async`. Why? Because I am doing a course on Coursera and I have to upload a JavaScript/Node file as assignment. The one I wrote with `async` and `promise` got rejected (for that version look at the end of this post). Somehow input and output is not working with the "Coursera system".

So I am trying to do it without any bells and whistles:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});

const r2 = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});

let x = null;
let y = [];

rl.on('line', line1 => {
  if (line1 !== "\n") {
    x = parseInt(line1);
    while(x > 0){
      r2.on('line', line2 => {
        y.push(line2);
      });
      x -= 1;
    }

    console.log('You entered these colors:', y);
    process.exit();
  }
});
```

Output:

```
3
You entered these colors: []
```

Expected output:

```
[input]3
[input]green
[input]blue
[input]red
[output]You entered these colors: ["green", "blue", "red"]
```

One that worked but rejected buy Coursera "assignment system":

```
const readline = require('readline');

const readLineAsync = () => {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    terminal: false
  });

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    rl.prompt();
    rl.on('line', (line) => {
      rl.close();
      resolve(line);
    });
  });
};

async function start() {
  let line = null;
  let colors = [];

  line = await readLineAsync();
  const numColors = parseInt(line);

  for(let count = numColors; count > 0; count--) {
    line = await readLineAsync();
    colors.push(line);
  }

  console.log('You entered these colors:', colors);
}

start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, we want to ask how many colors the user intends to enter. We are sure the input is expected only once so `r1.once()` is used.

But, the number of times we ask the user for input varies according to the previous input. So we use `r1.on()` which [will not close until terminated](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html). We will use a variable, `counter`, to ensure the input is asked of the user the required number of times.

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    terminal: false
});

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

rl.once('line', line => {
    const count = parseInt(line.toString());
    const colors = [];
    let counter = 0;

    rl.on('line', line => {
        const color = readLine(line);
        colors.push(color);

        if(++counter >= count) {
            console.log('You have entered these colros:', colors);
            process.exit();
        }
    });
});

function readLine(line) {
    return line.toString();
}
```

*output*

```sh
3
red
green
blue
You have entered these colros: [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ]
```